# Elasticsearch curator : Example does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying to follow the simple example at

http://curator.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.1/examples.html

```
import elasticsearch
import curator

client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

indices = curator.get_indices(client)
filter_list = []
filter_list.append(curator.build_filter(kindOf='prefix', value='ab'))
filter_list.append(
    curator.build_filter(
        kindOf='older_than', value=30, time_unit='days',
        timestring='%Y.%d.%m'
    )
)
filter_list.append(
    curator.build_filter(
        kindOf='newer_than', value=14, time_unit='days',
        timestring='%Y-%d-%m'
    )
)
working_list = indices
for filter in filter_list:
    working_list = curator.apply_filter(working_list, **filter)
curator.show(working_list)
```

but i get

```
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (ab-2016-05-27 ab-2016-05-26 ab-2016-05-25 ab-2016-05-24 ab-2016-05-28)
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Try to change the time strings to `%Y-%d-%m`

Comment: did that. same result

Comment: Where's the error showing up?  After which statement is that showing up?

Comment: on curator.show(working_list)

Comment: it works with `curator.api.show(client=es_client, object_list=working_list, type='indices')` but for delete, i have to do `curator.delete(client=client, indices=working_list)` this can be a bit confusing